# Realtime Database onWrite triggers in Cloud Functions has null val() data

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement push notifications trigger using cloud functions in firebase but each time I try the val function returns null. It is not recognizing the pushID, I implemented database from android using push() method.
This is my database structure 
 [image]

And this is my code for push notifications whenever a Post is created.

```
  //import firebase functions modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Posts/Posts/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var valueObject = event.data.val();

    // if(valueObject.photoUrl != null) {
    //   valueObject.photoUrl= "Sent you a photo!";
    // }

  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:valueObject.tittle,
            body: valueObject.details,
            sound: "default"
        },
    };

  //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };


    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});
```

This is error in console of cloud functions

[image]

Edited after using OnCreate:-

```
   exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Posts/Posts/{pushid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

const original = snapshot.val();
    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    // var valueObject = event.data.val();
 var valueObject = snap.val();
    // if(valueObject.photoUrl != null) {
    //   valueObject.photoUrl= "Sent you a photo!";
    // }

  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:valueObject.tittle,
            body: valueObject.details,
            sound: "default"
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't adapted your code to the new Functions 1.0 SDK.  The differences are detailed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

As you can see from that doc in the [Realtime Database section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database), onWrite triggers now give you a Change object with `before` and `after` properties that you use to get the value of the database location before or after the update.

Also consider if you actually want an onCreate trigger instead, which is more straightforward to deal with, and only triggers once when data at the matching location is newly created.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have updated my code and I am now using onCreate. But now it returns null on my tittle field,
Error: function execution failed. Details:
Cannot read property 'tittle' of null. 


However in my database my Posts do have a tittle attribute. It seems the problem is with {pushId},I think I can't seem to recover push Key as a child or as a reference to work with. Is pushId the only wildcard used to recover pushed items? I used push() method from my android code.

Comment: If you have a followup question that's different than the first, please explain and illustrate the new question separately.